# problem of self thesholding in saving pictures in a dataset in python

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, computer-vision, numpy-ndarray

I am providing a dataset for learning a CNN using data-augmentation to detect a soduko in a bigger image.
My dataset is using edge-detected soduko feature to learn a CNN. In the first step I wrote a data-loader to get pictures and save them to a n-dimensional numpy array(X).

```
def load_data(n):
X = np.ndarray((n, datasize, datasize,1) )
Y = []
truenumber = 1
falsenumber = 1
for i in range(n):
    if i % int((n/100)) == 0 :
        print("{} precent of data loaded".format(int(i / n * 100)))

    rnd = np.random.randint(8360)

    if rnd < 4000:
        pic = cv2.imread('F:\edu\machine vision projects\soduko with CNN\TrainSet\True\{}.png'.format(truenumber) , cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
        pic = np.resize(pic, (datasize,datasize))
        truenumber += 1
        if truenumber > 6380: continue
        Y.append(1)
        for a in range(datasize):
            for b in range(datasize):
                X[i,a,b,0] = pic[a,b]

    else:
        pic = cv2.imread('F:\edu\machine vision projects\soduko with CNN\TrainSet\False\{}.png'.format(falsenumber) , cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
        pic = np.resize(pic, (datasize,datasize))
        if falsenumber > 2080: continue
        falsenumber += 1
        Y.append(0)
        for a in range(datasize):
            for b in range(datasize):
                X[i, a, b, 0] = pic[a, b]

Y = np.asarray(Y)

return X , Y
```

as you see saving method of False and True datas are all the same but here we have :
[two examples of True and False returned images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d20uZ.png)

as you see it for True numbers it makes kind of a threshold as it should not do. would any one possibly know why?

Comment: Can you please specify where exactly in the code you are handling the Threshold part. Also, can you please clarify why are you not using Keras `ImageDataGenerator.flow_from_directory ` to load the Images and to convert them to Numpy Arrays?

Comment: Piont is I never implemented any threshold on images, It does it by its self!

Comment: about using keras There is no specific reason. I just did it with `imread` . Thanks for advice I will use that.